# How to calulate the height of one div and increase another in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following problem.

I have a paneldiv1 which contains come content - as I decrease the browser size the content bunches up and increase the height of the div which is fine.

As paneldiv1 increase is height I would like paneldiv2 to recalculate its size depending on the size of paneldiv1.

SO if paneldiv1 is 100px height and increase by 20px to 120px

and paneldiv2 has a height of 150px - i'd want paneldiv2 to increase by 20px = to 170px

how can I do this in jquery??

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/9CvzV/

Comment: Probably not a good idea to do this in javascript, try to change your layout in CSS so it adjusts appropriately. Maybe even look into media queries.

Comment: The reason I want it done in javascript is that the main container is using the browser scroll bar and these paneldivs are fixed - so i need to recalculate the height somehow..

Comment: paneldiv2 is in the scolling area which needs to recalculate its size depending on paneldiv1 - is this possible?